# How to update binded to WindowsForms.TextBox.DataSource.. mmm.. data source on every TextChanged event (during typing)?

Tags: .net, winforms, data-binding, textbox

How to update binded to WindowsForms.TextBox.DataSource.. mmm.. data source on every TextChanged event (during typing)?

That is useful if you want to update some "counters" or "error statuses" when you are typing.

Sometimes ago I've used this code, but it looks too complex. May be there are other simpler solution?

```
class FlashTextBox:TextBox
{
  protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
  {
   Binding binding = this.DataBindings["Text"];
   if (binding!=null)
   {
    PropertyManager propertyManager = 
                                binding.BindingManagerBase as PropertyManager;
    if (propertyManager!=null)
    {
               PropertyInfo pinfo =      
                                    binding.DataSource.GetType()
                                    .GetProperty(binding.BindingMemberInfo.BindingField,
                                    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
     pinfo.SetValue(binding.DataSource, this.Text, null);
    } 
   }
                    if (isAutoScrollVisible)
                    {
                            ChangeScrollVisibility();
                    }
   base.OnTextChanged (e);
  }

  const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
  public override bool PreProcessMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message msg)
  {
   if(msg.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN)
   {
    switch((Int32)msg.WParam)
    {
     case (int)Keys.Enter :
      if (EnterPressed!=null)
       EnterPressed(this,EventArgs.Empty);
      break;
    }
   } 
   return base.PreProcessMessage(ref msg);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code snippet shows how you can bind TextBox.Text property to a business object's PropertyName property. Make sure you set the DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged setting as the DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation is the default for TextBox controls.

```
var bindingSource = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource();
bindingSource.DataSource = businessObject;
flashTextBox.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding(
    "Text", 
    bindingSource, 
    "PropertyName", 
    true, 
    System.Windows.Forms.DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged
    ));
```

Refer to MSDN documentation for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.aspx